# Join performance in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgres-10

I have 2 tables **scheduling_flownode** and **xact_message** with weak relation between them. I am trying to execute the following query

```sql
set search_path='ad_96d5be';
explain analyze 
SELECT f.id, f.target_object_id 
FROM "scheduling_flownode" f, 
     "xact_message" m 
where f.target_object_id = m.id 
and f.root_node=True 
AND f.state=1 
and m.state=4 
and m.templatelanguage_id IN (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
```

On execution, I get the following query plan

```
  Gather  (cost=252701.26..1711972.04 rows=374109 width=8) (actual time=17737.908..164181.063 rows=441130 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=35705 read=1346425, temp read=18190 written=18148
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=251701.26..1673561.14 rows=155879 width=8) (actual time=18805.587..163991.468 rows=147043 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (f.target_object_id = m.id)
         Buffers: shared hit=35705 read=1346425, temp read=18190 written=18148
         ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on scheduling_flownode f  (cost=124367.21..1523127.76 rows=2061083 width=8) (actual time=963.910..155466.840 rows=1642157 loops=3)
               Recheck Cond: (state = 1)
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 44
               Filter: root_node
               Rows Removed by Filter: 12406874
               Heap Blocks: exact=10570 lossy=427078
               Buffers: shared read=1328631
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "root-node-and-state"  (cost=0.00..123130.57 rows=4946600 width=0) (actual time=955.044..955.045 rows=4926472 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((root_node = true) AND (state = 1))
                     Buffers: shared read=13464
         ->  Hash  (cost=120677.64..120677.64 rows=405712 width=4) (actual time=7124.131..7124.131 rows=441128 loops=3)
               Buckets: 131072  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 2966kB
               Buffers: shared hit=35591 read=17793, temp written=3384
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on xact_message m  (cost=7893.56..120677.64 rows=405712 width=4) (actual time=61.307..6925.456 rows=441128 loops=3)
                     Recheck Cond: (state = 4)
                     Filter: (templatelanguage_id = ANY ('{17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}'::integer[]))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                     Heap Blocks: exact=16585
                     Buffers: shared hit=35591 read=17793
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "state-index"  (cost=0.00..7792.13 rows=421826 width=0) (actual time=58.781..58.781 rows=441132 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: (state = 4)
                           Buffers: shared hit=2420 read=1209
 Planning time: 1.382 ms
 Execution time: 164289.481 ms
(31 rows)
```

**scheduling_flownode** here has over 400,00,000 entries and **xact_message** has about 50,00,000 rows. Working on postgres 10, am I wrong to believe that this much load should be handled easily by postgres ? If it can, am I doing something wrong with the query here ?

Comment: The statistics are way off. Does running `analyze scheduling_flownode;` change anything?

Comment: It depends on your hardware, your other load, and your indexing.

Comment: Hardware includes AWS RDS server 8GB RAM, 200 GB Memory and indexes are as per the query plan. There's absolutely no other load on the system. Single query running

Comment: `\d scheduling_flownode`,  `\d xact_message` are needed. I would say that `target_object_id` should be indexed, also your execution plan looks strange - what is `(root_node AND (date_part('month'::text, created) = '6'::double precision))`??? Please call `explain` once again, with provided query.

Comment: Updated the comment to remove datepart. Sorry for the confusion. Just been trying too many things. Also, there's an index on target_object_id already but postgres isnt using it

Comment: try creating the following 2 indexes which should cover your query: { scheduling_flownode (state, root_node, target_object_id, id) } and { xact_message (state, template_language, id) }. Also try to change the template language predicate to m.templatelanguage_id BETWEEN 17 AND 24.

Comment: I have those indexes but somehow postgres is not using the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show what indexes you have, but I strongly recommend that your indexes will cover all of the columns that you are filtering on.

In Postgres 11 that can be done by using [COVERING indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-index-only-scans.html), so for example on table `scheduling_flownode` you will have an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_scheduling_flownode_target_object_id 
  ON scheduling_flownode(target_object_id) 
    INCLUDE (state, root_node);
```

In Postgres 10 simply include the columns in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_scheduling_flownode_target_object_id 
  ON scheduling_flownode(target_object_id, state, root_node);
```

Do the same for table `xact_message` with `templatelanguage_id` and `state`.

Comment: We added this query but it seems that postgres doesnt use it while querying